# Click on Link and View in Another Section of Page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem, how to view the data I want when click on one of link. How can I get the dynamic id to trigger the data.

Below is my image, when I click on `Shay, Linn. 2015 .....` on Metadata section it will show the detail dynamically on Detail section.
[image]

Here is my code:

```
<td><a href="">Shay, Lynn. 2015. Tropical Cyclone Issac Ocean Profiles from 16 August 2012. Deepsea to Coast Connectivity in the Eastern Gulf of Mexico (DEEP-C). </a></td>
```

And below is my code of Detail section

```
<div class="panel-body">
            <p align="justify"><strong>Dataset Title:</strong> Tropical Cyclone Issac Ocean Profiles from 16 August 2012</p>
            <p align="justify"><strong>File Identifier:</strong> R1.x138.077:0015</p>
            <p align="justify"><strong>Dataset Originator:</strong> Shay, Lynn</p>
            <p align="justify"><strong>Point of Contact:</strong> Shay, Lynn (nshay@rsmas.miami.edu) </p>
            <p align="justify"><strong>Abstract:</strong> <br />A flight on NOAA's WP-3D Orion aircraft was conducted during tropical cyclone Isaac on 16 August 2012 over the northeastern Gulf of Mexico (from approximately 24 to 29 N and 84 to 90 W), over the Loop Current (LC) and associated frontal eddies. Airborne expendable probes measured atmospheric and oceanic parameters.</p>
            <br />
            <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" href="metaservice#">Metaservice</a>
        </div>
```

How can I do that? Thanks before

Comment: Are you looking for a solution using plain javascript or are you happy with a solution using jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem simply with only javascript and html you will need to print out all of the information to the page and show / hide the relevant details when you need them.

My html has a `.panel-body` div for each detail. Notice they each have unique Ids. These are hidden by default in the css. I've also given each link in the metadata (which you will probably want to style up better) a unique `data-id` attribute (1 & 2), I've also given them the class of `metalink` so I can reference them easily in the javascript. I've cut the details panels down a bit to make it easier to read.

My javascript gets all of the `metalink`s and binds a click handler to each one by running through them in the for loop. This then goes to the showDetail(id) method that hides all of the detail panels and then shows the one with the id that we passed through from the click event. There's probably a more elegant way of doing this by checking each div in each iteration to determine whether to show it or not, but this works too.

I've included a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9ujjoywp/1/) to see this in action, with some quick & dirty styling.

HTML:

```
  <div id="metadata">
    <h1>Metadata</h1>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Metadata</th>
        <th>Download</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="#" class="metalink" data-id="1">11111111111111111</a></td>
        <td>Download</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="#" class="metalink" data-id="2">22222222222222222</a></td>
        <td>Download</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div id="detail">
    <h1>Detail</h1>

    <div id="panel-1" class="panel-body">
      <p align="justify">Details for 111111111</p>
    </div>

    <div id="panel-2" class="panel-body">
      <p align="justify">Details for 22222222</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
var metalinks = document.getElementsByClassName("metalink");
  for (var i=0; i < metalinks.length; i++) {
    metalinks[i].onclick = function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      showDetail(this.dataset.id);
    };
}

function showDetail(id)
{
  var detailsPanels = document.getElementsByClassName("panel-body");
  for (var j=0; j < detailsPanels.length; j++) {
    detailsPanels[j].style.display = "none";
  }
  var detailPanel = document.getElementById("panel-" + id);
  detailPanel.style.display = "block";
}
```